# Why is this Python generator functioning like this?

Tags: python

I was looking into this article by [RealPython](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) about Python generators. It uses a palindrome generator as a exemplary tool to explain the `.send`, `.throw` and `.close` methods. Building a program following their instructions gives the following code:

```py
def infinite_palindromes():
    num = 0
    while True:
        if is_palindrome(num):
            i = (yield num)
            if i is not None:
                num = i
        num += 1


def is_palindrome(num):
    # Skip single-digit inputs
    if num // 10 == 0:
        return False
    temp = num
    reversed_num = 0

    while temp != 0:
        reversed_num = (reversed_num * 10) + (temp % 10)
        temp = temp // 10

    if num == reversed_num:
        return True
    else:
        return False


pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()
for e in pal_gen:
    digits = len(str(e))
    pal_gen.send(10**(digits))
```

I watched the flow of the program in debugging and what happens is basically, when the function finds `11`, the first palindrome, it enters into the `for e` loop block, the `digits` variable is defined, and 10 to the power of that variable value is sent back to the generator. 100 is sent back, and since it is different from `None`, num is equated to i and becomes 100, then it's summed with 1 and becomes 101, the next palindrome. Here is what I don't get: when that number is throw and correctly identified as a palindrome, the code goes back to the `for e in pal_gen:` line, but it doesn't enter the block. Only the next palindrome, `111` is sent back down and enters the block, where the `digits` variable is defined again, and so on and so forth, and this patterns repeats, with only every other palindrome entering the block. Why is that?

Can someone, please, explain to me why that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the behaviour, we need to understand [how `for` loops are implemented in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292189). This code:

```
for e in pal_gen:
    digits = len(str(e))
    pal_gen.send(10**(digits))
```

is basically equivalent to (except that no name `_iter` is actually generated):

```
_iter = iter(pal_gen)
while True:
    try:
        e = next(_iter)
        digits = len(str(e))
        pal_gen.send(10**(digits))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

However, because `pal_gen` is a generator object (created by calling the generator function `infinite_palindromes`), it is already an iterator; calling `iter` on it returns the **same object** unchanged. Thus, we effectively have:

```
while True:
    try:
        e = next(pal_gen)
        digits = len(str(e))
        pal_gen.send(10**(digits))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

The other thing to note here is that calling `.send` on a generator *advances the generator, and so does* passing it to `next` (i.e., using it like any other iterator). It's just that the code was written to ignore the value retrieved using `.send`.

In fact, `next` on a generator is equivalent to calling `.send` and passing `None` (by convention; Python defines the behaviour this way so that the assignment in the generator code, `i = (yield num)`, has something to assign).

So, each time through the loop, two values are sent to the generator:

```
while True:
    try:
        e = pal_gen.send(None)
        digits = len(str(e))
        pal_gen.send(10**(digits))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

The control flow is like so:

- `None` is sent to the generator. Because it hasn't yielded yet, this value is discarded (Python requires it to be `None`, since it can't be used by the generator).
- The generator iterates its own loop until `11` is found and yielded. The execution of the generator pauses here: `i` is not assigned yet.
- The main loop receives `11` as a value for `e`, computes `100` as the next value to work with, and sends that to the generator.
- The generator receives `100` and assigns it to `i`, then proceeds with its logic. The next step is `if i is not None:`, and that is indeed the case - thus, `100` is assigned to `num`. `num` is incremented at the end of the loop.
- The loop inside the generator runs into the next iteration, and immediately finds that `101` is a palindrome. Thus, the `.send` call returns a value of `101`, but this isn't assigned anywhere.
- Similarly, in the second iteration of the main loop, `111` will be found and yielded (as the next palindrome after `101`) and assigned to `e` in the first call; then `1000` is sent explicitly, causing `1001` to be yielded and ignored. In the third iteration, `1111` is assigned to `e`, then `10001` is ignored. In the fourth iteration, `10101` (not `11111`! This is the next palindrome after `10001`) is assigned, and `100001` is ignored. Etc.

If the code is tested at the REPL, the values returned from the explicit `.send` will be displayed. This is just a quirk of the REPL.

Comment: I see. I still don't quite get but this answer gives me a great base to keep trying to figure out on  my own. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Specifically for generators, following along with a debugger might not be the easiest way to understand. Here's a more popular question with general background information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715758

Comment: Thank you, but I actually managed to understand what was happening once I reread your explanation a few more times and experimented trying to deal with that ignored send value. Putting an empty yield inside the if block in the function, after the num = i bit, makes the generator not skip every other palindrome. Thank you a whole lot for the help and support.